# Getting a Regex for an "A.B"

Tags: regex

I am using the (very awesome) ["Autocomplete Menu"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/365974/AutocompleteMenu.zip) to validate some SQL code for me.  The Automcomplete menu uses Regex to suggest autocomplete items.

The default Regex is

```
[\w\.]
```

which works fine for words with a whitespace boundary.  Essentially, I have a set of SQL keywords, and a set of Tables and Fields that are commonly used.  Using our database, my queries need to prefix the table name.  To get it to work properly, what I want is to get the autocomplete menu to treat a "." as whitespace.  I.e. at the moment, if I have a Table called "PEOPLE" that has a field called "FIRST_NAME", I want the autocomplete to trigger at:
    PEOPLE.FIR
to give me the "FIRST_NAME" option.

I.e. at present it works if I type **FIR**, but not if I type **PEOPLE.FIR**

Is there a Regex that anyone can suggest that will treat the "." as a word boundary?  I tried searching a few regex sites, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Please explain how do you think the regex `[\w.]` works. If you understand it, the solution is trivial.

Comment: you mean this `[\w.]+`?

Comment: Sorry - I was incorrect.  The default regex is [\w\.].  I'm a novice at Regex, but I understand that the square brackets mean it looks for a match of any character within the brackets.  The \w looks for anything alphanumeric.  The \. matches a "." as well.  The problem is that I don't actually want to match a ".", I want it to be interpreted as whitespace (I guess I could prepend a "." on each fieldname).

Comment: @ainwood: Yes, so remove the dot from the character class so that it doesn't get matched!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the literal dot from the regex if you do not want it to match literal dots.

Comment: Wow - it really was that easy!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `PEOPLE\.FIR`

The `\` character escapes the `.` and tells it to interpret `.` as `.` itself.

Comment: Thanks.  The escape character got formatted-out when I posted the question.  the actual regex is [ \ w \ . ].  I don't want to match on this, I actually want the '.' to be treated as whitespace.